# Is it possible to read the log file of App1 by App2 in android (non-rooted android device)?

Tags: android, android-logcat

Is it possible to read the log file of App1 by App2 in android (non-rooted android device)?

I want to read the logs of an app say APP1 by other app on the same device say APP2.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: What kind of logs ? Default Android logging or something you're logging manually in the App1 ?

Comment: Default Android logging @Jabbar_Jigariyo

Comment: @Uttam5oren then, NO. Not possible